# How to finish current activity and launch a new activity Rx way?

Tags: android, android-activity, rx-java2

I want to do the following but in Rx. The `startActivity(intent)` is guaranteed to be called since `finish()` is just an async call queued:

```
private fun launchNewActivity(){
  ...
  finish()
  startActivity(intent)
}
```

So in Rx way, I'm doing something like this, where both are packaged in their own observables (requirement):

```
private fun launchNewActivity(): Observable<Any>{
  ...
  return Observable.concat(
    Observable.just(finish())
    Observable.just(startActivity(intent))
    ...
  )
}
```

However, I'm worried in the Rx way, the activity *could* finish before startActivity is called. Would that happen?

Comment: try to call startActivity first than finish

Comment: In our use case, we actually don't want to do that. There's an edge case, where calling `finish()` first has an advantage.

Comment: What's the type returned by `finish()` and provided with the observable?

Comment: The actual call is something like `finishActivityAction()`, which calls finish() and returns an object "RoutingResult".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually you are calling it in a wrong order. You should call `startActivity()` first before calling `finish()`. Still, encapsulating this process inside an Observable **might introduce an unexpected behavior**, because `startActivity()` is supposed to be called on UI thread as it triggers UI animation/transition to another Activity.

What you want to do is to call both `startActivity()` and `finish()` inside `onNext()` or `onComplete()` callback. But in case you REALLY need to encapsulate it, you can follow these simple steps:

**1. Create a method which handles Activity switching**

```
private fun launchNewActivity() {
    startActivity(Intent())
    finish()
}
```

**2. Encapsulate this method in Observable**

```
Observable.fromCallable(this::launchNewActivity)
```

You will want to put above Observable inside a `CompositeDisposable` or a `DisposableObserver`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Start Your Next Activity Before Finish this Actvity.

First start your activity `startactivity(Intent(this,NextActivity::Class.java)`
and after call `finish()` it work as finish your current activity.

here you can find code:

```
public fun startNewActivity(){
 startActivity(Intent(this,NewActivity::Class.java))
 finish()
}
```